# Selecting last record from INNER JOIN and grouping

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Okay so I have a query that selects 1 message from each user that is ordered by date DESC but selects the first message for each group.. I need to select the last message by date from each group (each user)
This is my query:

```
SELECT     people.id, 
           people.avatar, 
           people.firstname, 
           people.lastname, 
           LEFT(messages.message, 90) AS message, 
           messages.seen, 
           messages.date 
FROM       people 
INNER JOIN messages 
ON         people.id = messages.sender_id 
WHERE      reciever_id = '". $user_data['id'] ."' 
GROUP BY   sender_id 
ORDER BY   date DESC limit 11
```

Comment: That query is not grouped by date. It is grouped by sender_id. It doesn't show the first message of each group. It shows all messages in descending date order.

Comment: Typo sorry, il correct it

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse my syntax if it is a bit off, but I would probably try something like this.

```
SELECT people.id, 
       people.avatar, 
       people.firstname, 
       people.lastname, 
       LEFT(msg.message, 90) AS message, 
       msg.seen, 
       msg.date 
FROM  people 
INNER JOIN (SELECT message, seen, date, sender_id
                FROM messages GROUP By sender_id 
                ORDER By date DESC LIMIT 1) msg
                ON people.id = msg.sender_id
WHERE      reciever_id = '". $user_data['id'] ."'
```

Comment: I get the #1054 - Unknown column in 'Field List'

Comment: Are you testing it directly against the database without that where clause?

Comment: No, "WHERE" is in the query