# Selecting last record from inner joined records

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a post 6 days ago but no one seemed to anwser correctly and it was eventually abandoned so here I post it again (sorry for DPing but this is important to me)
I have 2 tables - people (query is based on people.id so no need to ss the entire table) and messages (http://prntscr.com/94iq2e)

I have a query which is grouping messages with people and that is working fine but each person is grouped with the first message he sent and I need to make it so that it groups people with the LAST message they sent

Here is the query which is grouping people with the FIRST message

```
SELECT     people.id, 
       people.avatar, 
       people.firstname, 
       people.lastname, 
       LEFT(messages.message, 90) AS message, 
       messages.seen, 
       messages.date 
FROM       people 
INNER JOIN messages 
ON         people.id = messages.sender_id 
WHERE      reciever_id = '". $user_data['id'] ."' 
GROUP BY   sender_id 
ORDER BY   date DESC limit 11
```

Link to the previous topic -> [Selecting last record from INNER JOIN and grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680396/selecting-last-record-from-inner-join-and-grouping)

Comment: You really need to parameterize your queries and avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery that returns the maximum date:

```
SELECT sender_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
FROM messages
GROUP BY sender_id
```

and join people table with this subquery, and then join to the messages table to get the message with the maximum date:

```
SELECT
   people.id, 
   people.avatar, 
   people.firstname, 
   people.lastname, 
   LEFT(messages.message, 90) AS message, 
   messages.seen, 
   messages.date 
FROM
   people INNER JOIN (
     SELECT sender_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
     FROM messages
     GROUP BY sender_id
   ) lm ON people.id = lm.sender_id
   INNER JOIN messages 
   ON people.id = messages.sender_id AND
      lm.max_date=messages.date
WHERE
   reciever_id = ...
ORDER BY
   ...
```

Comment: SELECT
      people.id, 
      people.avatar, 
      people.firstname, 
      people.lastname, 
      LEFT(lm.message, 90) AS message, 
      lm.seen, 
      lm.date 
   FROM
      people INNER JOIN (
     SELECT sender_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
     FROM messages
     GROUP BY sender_id
      ) lm ON people.id = lm.sender_id
      INNER JOIN messages 
      ON people.id = messages.sender_id
      WHERE reciever_id = '". $user_data['id'] ."'
      GROUP BY messages.sender_id

I get the 1054 error

Comment: @Champa it's not lm.message, lm.seen, ... please try with messages.message, messages.seen, etc. (see my updated answer, I quickly fixed it)

Comment: Oh God.. I'm in such a hurry that i even didnt notice that lol Anyways SELECT
   people.id, 
   people.avatar, 
   people.firstname, 
   people.lastname, 
   LEFT(messages.message, 90) AS message, 
   messages.seen, 
   messages.date 
FROM
   people INNER JOIN (
     SELECT sender_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
     FROM messages
     GROUP BY sender_id
   ) messages ON people.id = messages.sender_id
   INNER JOIN messages 
   ON people.id = messages.sender_id AND
      messages.max_date=messages.date
      WHERE reciever_id = '". $user_data['id'] ."'
      GROUP BY messages.sender_id
 - ERROR 1052

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a sub query to pull out the latest messages. The below link may of help to you, it details a few possible solutions.

[SQL join: selecting the last records in a one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship)

Cheers,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

I dont know mysql but in TSQL it would be like this to get last message:

```
ISNULL(SELECT TOP 1 messages.message FROM messages WHERE people.id = messages.sender_id ORDER BY messages.id DESC,'')
```

---

Whole code would look like this:

```
 SELECT     people.id, 
   people.avatar, 
   people.firstname, 
   people.lastname, 
   ISNULL(SELECT TOP 1 messages.message FROM messages WHERE people.id = messages.sender_id ORDER BY messages.id DESC,'') AS message, 
   messages.seen, 
   messages.date 
FROM       people 
INNER JOIN messages 
ON         people.id = messages.sender_id 
WHERE      reciever_id = '". $user_data['id'] ."' 
GROUP BY   sender_id 
ORDER BY   date DESC limit 11
```